# What is causing the strange behaviour of hover when the class has a certain name?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am having trouble pinning down a fault within my programme. There seems to be some odd behaviour with the link, or 'a' element. Whenever I name the class of the section below middle it disables the hover pseudo class on an unrelated section. If I name it anything else e.g. fiddle or make it an ID instead of a class it works fine.

Can anyone she some light on why this class name is causing the behaviour.

```css
.middle {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
}

.select {
  position: absolute;
  background: light gray;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.button-select:hover a {
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<section class="select">
  <div class="button-select "><a href="uploads.php">My uploads</a></div>
  <div class="button-select current"><a href="course.php">My courses</a></div>
  <div class="button-select"><a href="account.php">My account</a></div>
  <div class="button-select"><a href="ratings.php">My ratings</a></div>
</section>


<section class="middle">
</section>

<!-- renaming the class fiddle removes the problem!
      <section class="fiddle"></section>-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `.middle` section is set to 800px height and that's making it cover your links. It probably works when you change the class name because you forgot to change the CSS to match.

I just removed the height from the CSS and it works.

If you need, the `.middle` section to be 800px in height, I suggest moving the `.select` section inside `.middle` so that it will not be covered.

```css
.middle {
  position: relative;
}

.select {
  position: absolute;
  background: light gray;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.button-select:hover a {
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<section class="select">
  <div class="button-select "><a href="uploads.php">My uploads</a></div>
  <div class="button-select current"><a href="course.php">My courses</a></div>
  <div class="button-select"><a href="account.php">My account</a></div>
  <div class="button-select"><a href="ratings.php">My ratings</a></div>
</section>
<section class="middle">
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you I am going to set the offending with a left offset position so it does not overlay the links. I not sure I would have been able to figure this out without help though !

Comment: It was very easy to figure out using the developer tools in the browser. I simply right-clicked on the `.middle` element and selected "inspect element". Then, looking at the element highlighting, it was obvious that it was overlapping your links.

I suggest getting familiar with your browser's developer tools because they are extremely useful for debugging.

Comment: Yes a very good point. I have started to color my Div's dark green when this happens to make it more obvious what is going on, it has really helped. I have started to use the Chrome developer tool which is very useful for this.

Answer (score 1):

Class Name `fiddle` is working fine now. and removed `position: relative` from `.fiddle` css

Hope This will helps you

```css
.select {
position:absolute;
background: light gray;
padding:10px;
border-radius: 6px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
float:left;
box-shadow: 5px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}


.button-select:hover a {

color: white;
background-color:  #333;

}
.fiddle {
height:800px;
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
    </head>

    <body>


        <section  class="select">
           <div class="button-select "><a href="uploads.php">My uploads</a></div>
           <div class="button-select current"><a href="course.php">My courses</a></div>
           <div class="button-select"><a href="account.php">My account</a></div>
           <div class="button-select"><a href="ratings.php">My ratings</a></div>
        </section> 


         <section class="fiddle">     
         </section> 

        <!-- 
        renaming the class fiddle removes the problem!
  <section class="fiddle">
   </section> 
 -->

   </body>

</html>
```